# Taking physical gold out of the United States

Tags: united-states, gold

Are there restrictions on taking physical gold out of the US if I emigrate? Can I just pack it in my luggage and get on a plane to UK?

Comment: what country are you entering? They may also have laws regarding bringing gold into their country.

Comment: I did a bit of googling, but do not have time to compose an answer.  Yes, you can take gold out of the US.  You may have to fill out some forms --not sure about this.   You do have to fill out forms if you bring in more than $10,000 worth of gold.  The gold should be coins or bullion.  Bringing in or out a mass of gold jewelry could be different.  Further, It seems that the airline does not care.   As for bringing the gold into the country that you are moving to, it could depend on the country.  (This comment should not be regarded as an authoritative answer.)

Comment: How much, and in what form?  If it's a significant amount, you might be exceeding the airline's weight limits for carry-on luggage.  OTOH, if it's just a few coins, I'd just put them in my pocket with the rest of my change :-)

Comment: @ab2 [Please do not answer the question in the comments.](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2299/10997) Even if you are unsure of your answer or your answer is not as complete as you would like, you need to allow your answer to be subject to the community moderation features. This is especially important if your answer (which you are unsure of) turns out to be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The US Border Patrol website says this:
"
Report Traveling with $10,000 or more: There is no limit to how much currency you may take in or out of the United States; however, U.S. federal law requires you to report your total currency of $10,000 or more. Currency includes all forms of monetary instruments. Travelers who fail to truthfully report all of their currency risk their currency being seized, and may face criminal charges.
"

Link here: 
https://www.cbp.gov/newsroom/local-media-release/what-international-travelers-should-know-you-go-summer-az

The UK Border Agency website has a less simple answer involving the EU and Non-EU countries. The limit for declaration is over 10,000 euros. The declaration form link and more details can be found here:
https://www.gov.uk/bringing-cash-into-uk

Comment: I think the currency limits would only apply to the face value of the coins, which would presumably be well below the limits. Any restrictions on the actual value would not be currency limits, but other restrictions on goods or collectibles.

Answer (score -1):

The airlines say not to put valuables in checked luggage. But both passengers and carry-on luggage are searched for metal. Obviously, the gold owner does not want the security gate personnel to be juggling their gold.

Also, if the gold were in carry-on baggage then every time someone was pulling something out of a bag, the gold owner would want to stand-up and watch their  own bag. So the gold should be carried in a sling on the gold owner's body and under a coat.

A kilogram of gold is worth about $45,000. Suppose an investigator asked for an origin-of-funds ? And so paperwork on the gold is recommended.

If the gold is shipped as cargo then it can be insured. Then both the shipping company and the insurance company could have requirements.